# String or unsigned char to uint8_t

Tags: esp8266, string, eeprom, platformio

I'm attempting to save a string to EEPROM of an ESP8266 radio and then read it back before I encrypt the data (evenutally I would like to save the encrypted data but I'm simplifing things at the moment). Here is the source code:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
extern "C" 
{
    #include "cryptoauthlib.h"
}
#include "aes_cbc.h"
#include <EEPROM.h>
// Key Slot number
uint8_t KEY_SLOT = (uint8_t)9;

ATCAIfaceCfg cfg;
ATCA_STATUS status;

void writeStringToEEPROM(int addrOffset, const String &strToWrite)
{
  byte len = strToWrite.length();
  EEPROM.write(addrOffset, len);
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
  {
    EEPROM.write(addrOffset + 1 + i, strToWrite[i]);
  }
}

String readStringFromEEPROM(int addrOffset)
{
  int newStrLen = EEPROM.read(addrOffset);
  char data[newStrLen + 1];
  for (int i = 0; i < newStrLen; i++)
  {
    data[i] = EEPROM.read(addrOffset + 1 + i);
  }
  data[newStrLen] = '\0'; 
  return String(data);
}


void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(74880);

    // Init the constuctor for the library
    cfg.iface_type = ATCA_I2C_IFACE;  // Type of communication -> I2C mode
    cfg.devtype = ATECC608A;          // Type of chip
    cfg.atcai2c.slave_address = 0X30; // I2C address of the Adafruit Breakout Board
    cfg.atcai2c.bus = 1;
    cfg.atcai2c.baud = 100000;
    cfg.wake_delay = 1500; // Delay of wake up (1500 ms)
    cfg.rx_retries = 20;
    atca_trace_config(stdout);
}

void loop()
{
    ATCA_STATUS status = atcab_init(&cfg);
    if (status != ATCA_SUCCESS)
    {
        Serial.println(F("atcab_init() failed : Code -> 0x"));
        Serial.println(status, HEX);
    }
    writeStringToEEPROM(0, "test");
    String retrievedString = readStringFromEEPROM(0);
    uint8_t plaintext = atoi(retrievedString.substring(1,3).c_str());
    uint8_t iv[IV_LENGTH_CBC];
    uint8_t cypherdata[sizeof(plaintext)];

    Serial.println("Beginning of the encryption !");
    status = aes_cbc_encrypt(&cfg, plaintext, sizeof(plaintext), iv, cypherdata, KEY_SLOT);
    if (status == ATCA_SUCCESS)
    {
        Serial.println("encrypted");
    }
    else
    {
        // See file atca_status.h for the code Error
        Serial.print(F("Impossible do the encryption | Code Error 0x"));
        Serial.println(status, HEX);
        return;
    }
}
```

and here is the error message:

[image]

EDIT**:
Found out that the "Save to EEPROM" portion of my code wasn't working so I corrected that. Here is the new code:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
extern "C" 
{
    #include "cryptoauthlib.h"
}
#include "aes_cbc.h"
#include <EEPROM.h>
// Key Slot number
uint8_t KEY_SLOT = (uint8_t)9;

ATCAIfaceCfg cfg;
ATCA_STATUS status;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(74880);
    // Init the constuctor for the library
    cfg.iface_type = ATCA_I2C_IFACE;  // Type of communication -> I2C mode
    cfg.devtype = ATECC608A;          // Type of chip
    cfg.atcai2c.slave_address = 0X30; // I2C address of the Adafruit Breakout Board
    cfg.atcai2c.bus = 1;
    cfg.atcai2c.baud = 100000;
    cfg.wake_delay = 1500; // Delay of wake up (1500 ms)
    cfg.rx_retries = 20;
    atca_trace_config(stdout);
}

void loop()
{
    ATCA_STATUS status = atcab_init(&cfg);
    if (status != ATCA_SUCCESS)
    {
        Serial.println(F("atcab_init() failed : Code -> 0x"));
        Serial.println(status, HEX);
    }
    uint addr = 0;
    struct 
    { 
      uint val = 0;
      char str[16] = "";
    } data;

    EEPROM.begin(512);// commit 512 bytes of ESP8266 flash (for "EEPROM" emulation)
    strcpy(data.str,"test");
    EEPROM.put(addr,data);
    EEPROM.commit();  
    EEPROM.get(addr,data);
    Serial.println(String(data.str));

    uint8_t plaintext = atoi(data.str);
    //uint8_t plaintext[16] = "test";
    uint8_t iv[IV_LENGTH_CBC];
    uint8_t cypherdata[sizeof(plaintext)];
    uint8_t decryptdata[sizeof(plaintext)];

    Serial.println("Beginning of the encryption !");
    status = aes_cbc_encrypt(&cfg, &plaintext, sizeof(plaintext), iv, cypherdata, KEY_SLOT);
    if (status == ATCA_SUCCESS)
    {
        Serial.println("encrypted");
        status = aes_cbc_decrypt(&cfg, cypherdata, sizeof(cypherdata), iv, decryptdata, KEY_SLOT);
        if (status == ATCA_SUCCESS)
        {
            Serial.print("Decrypted text is : ");
            for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(decryptdata); i++)
            {
                Serial.print((char)decryptdata[i]);
            }
            Serial.println("");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // See file atca_status.h for the code Error
        Serial.print(F("Impossible do the encryption | Code Error 0x"));
        Serial.println(status, HEX);
        return;
    }
    delay(1000);
}
```

Now I'm seeing this in the terminal (no errors on compile!):

```
encrypted
ERROR Decrypt : ATCA_BAD_PARAMI2C send 1 bytes to addr 0x30: 01
```

When I change (the aes_cbc_encrypt function expects a length of 16)

```
sizeof(plaintext)
```

to

```
16
```

I see:

```
Decrypted text is : ␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀l��?���?
```

When I proved that the encrypt/decrypt portion of my code was working, this is what "plaintext" was:

```
 uint8_t plaintext[16] = "test";
```

Comment: No text as image please. You can copy the error message as text into your question and format it the same way as the code

Comment: The function expects a pointer to the data. Try passing it by reference as `&plaintext`. Though I'm not sure if you really want that. The variable name `plaintext` suggests, that it should be text. Though it is just a number (8 bit unsigned integer)

Comment: Again, you seem to think, that `plaintext` contains a text message. It does not. `sizeof(plaintext)` is always 1, since `plaintext` has only 1 byte. You are encrypting a single "character", though not really a character, but the binary representation of the number. It really doesn't make any sense to me, that you would encrypt a single byte. Why are you doing the `atoi()` when assigning `plaintext`? The commented line suggests, that this should be an array containing a c string.

Comment: chrisl, 
In the other working code, I had

uint8_t plaintext[16] = "test";

Without the EEPROM bit, this worked. When I try replace "test" with data.str, it gives a compile error. If I need to call something other than plaintext, fine. I'm a hardware guy that is trying my best to get better at firmware, so sorry if I'm ignorant about simple things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function [`atoi()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi) tries to interpret a string as a textual
representation of a number written in decimal. For example, `atoi("42")`
returns the integer 42. Here:

```cpp
uint8_t plaintext = atoi(data.str);
```

You are asking it to interpret `"test"`, which does not look like a
number. In such a case, `atoi()` returns zero. I do not know what was
your intent, but it was probably not this.

Further down, you have

```cpp
uint8_t cypherdata[sizeof(plaintext)];
uint8_t decryptdata[sizeof(plaintext)];
```

Given that `plaintext` is a single byte, its length is one. Thus this is
declaring two arrays of length one. Again, you probably meant something
else.

---

From you comment, I understand that you want `plaintext` to represent
the string `"test"` as an array of `uint8_t`.
Since both `char` and `uint8_t` represent bytes, no conversion is
needed. You can simply use the address of the original `char` array and
“pretend” it is the address of an array of `uint8_t`:

```
uint8 *plaintext = (uint8_t *) data.str;
```

Comment: I just what the string "test" stored in EEPROM and then converted in to uint so it can be placed in the aes_cbc_encrypt function. I changed the atoi command to toInt and still get the same thing. I'll edit the post to explain that in the original aes_ebc_encrypt example, I was using `uint8 plaintext[16] = "test";` and that was working

Comment: that makes sense. That worked and I just put it 16 for the sizeof(plaintext). That should work for now. Thanks!